# Summarize data in two different ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cube, rollup

Suppose I have a table that stores customer names, device numbers, and a few flags. Some sample data looks something like this:

```
[CustomerName], [Device], [A], [B], [C]
'Customer A',   '1234',   1,   0,   0
'Customer A',   '1235',   1,   1,   1
'Customer A',   '1234',   1,   1,   1
'Customer B',   '1236',   1,   1,   0
'Customer B',   '1236',   1,   0,   0
'Customer C',   '1235',   1,   1,   1
```

I need a report that presents 3 types of data simultaneously:

- The total number of rows with each flag
- The number of rows with each flag per customer
- The number of unique devices that appear in any row with each flag

The first two items were relatively easy to create using `ROLLUP`, but the last item was trickier. The only way I could figure out how to do it was with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING([CustomerName]) = 1) THEN 'ALL CUSTOMERS' 
       ELSE [CustomerName] END [CustomerName], 
       COUNT(*) [Rows], 
       SUM(CAST([A] AS [int])) [A], 
       SUM(CAST([B] AS [int])) [B], 
       SUM(CAST([C] AS [int])) [C]
  FROM [MyTable]
 GROUP BY [CustomerName] WITH ROLLUP
 UNION
SELECT 'UNIQUE DEVICES', 
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN [A] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN [B] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN [C] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM (
    SELECT [Device],
           COUNT(*) [Rows], 
           SUM(CAST([A] AS [int])) [A], 
           SUM(CAST([B] AS [int])) [B], 
           SUM(CAST([C] AS [int])) [C]
      FROM [MyTable]
     GROUP BY [Device] ) q
```

Results:

```
[CustomerName],   [Rows], [A], [B], [C]
'ALL CUSTOMERS',  6,      6,   4,   3
'Customer A',     3,      3,   2,   2
'Customer B',     2,      2,   1,   0
'Customer C',     1,      1,   1,   1
'UNIQUE DEVICES', 3,      3,   3,   2
```

This works well enough for my purposes for now, but having not had much experience using `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` before, I thought I'd try to see if I could get rid of that `UNION` and have a single `SELECT`. From the [examples on MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx), `ROLLUP` supports multiple groupings, but I can't figure out how to get it to produce the results I want. Can anyone demonstrate how to use a single `SELECT` to get these results?

Comment: Group by, roll up and cube are hierarchical but your desired output isn't. What you have done is the only way to get the result you want :)

Comment: @P.Salmon that's what I was afraid of, but I keep thinking that it aught be possible somehow if I use a double-aggregation like I did in the second `SELECT`.

Comment: There are ways you can get this into a "single" query (i.e. not use the `UNION`) but they're all going to involve more complex/less understandable/less performant code than what you've already got. I can post an example later if you *really* want one or you can accept that @P.Salmon basically hit it on the head.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a report that presents 3 types of data simultaneously:

That doesn't necessarily mean you need one query.  The results you want are logically distinct.  There are other ways to gang them all together, but the simplest query is a union of all three:

```
select   CustomerName
       , count(*) as Rows
       , sum(cast(A as int)) as A
       , sum(cast(B as int)) as B
       , sum(cast(C as int)) as C
from T
group by CustomerName
UNION
select   'ALL CUSTOMERS'
       , count(*) as Rows
       , sum(cast(A as int)) as A
       , sum(cast(B as int)) as B
       , sum(cast(C as int)) as C
from T
UNION
select   'UNIQUE DEVICES'
       , count(*) as Rows
       , sum(A) as A
       , sum(B) as B
       , sum(C) as C
from (
       select   Device
              , max(cast(A as int)) as A
              , max(cast(B as int)) as B
              , max(cast(C as int)) as C
       from T
       group by Device
) as A
```

The whole rollup/cube thing was always a peculiar disaster.  If you benefit from its particulars, fine, use it, else I recommend giving it a wide berth.  I couldn't readily understand your query without your explanation; by contrast, I daresay the first two parts of mine are easily understood without explanation.

You could create views of each of the three `UNION` components, and arrange them in other, interesting ways (in addition to the One Big Query).

> Can anyone demonstrate how to use a single SELECT to get these results?

Your query and mine *are* both single `SELECT` statements; `UNION` is part of `SELECT`.  What I think you mean is, can it be done without `UNION`, and that answer is No.  Or, maybe "yes, but you won't like it".  As you yourself phrased the question, you want to summarize the data in *two different ways*.  Those two ways are *logically distinct*: by customer and by flag.  `UNION` is the relational algebra operator that concatenates two relations, which is exactly what you asked for!  :-)

SQL server also supports the [OVER clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx); it permits more complex kinds of grouping, and you might be able to get it to produce the desired results without a `UNION`.  But I doubt the SQL will be as easy to understand and change, or as few lines, as what you have so far.